# List of checkboxes in Propertygrid

Tags: vb.net, winforms, propertygrid

I want to encapsulate a dropdown checkbox list  (something like http://hanamidesign.com/blog/ui-pattern-drop-down-checkbox-list/) inside a propertygrid. Is it possible?

Comment: `PropertyGrid` is bound to a class and displays its `public` properties.  Create a class with all the `Boolean` properties you want and it will show them.

Comment: I don´t want to control a boolean property. I want to control a list of itens that has a boolean associated. For example, imagine that I have books written by 4 authors. The user can filter to show the books for two authors only. I want a way the user can choose the authors in the propertygrid.

Comment: Then you don't want a `PropertyGrid`, you want [CheckedListBox](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCUQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fsystem.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.checkeditems(v%3Dvs.110).aspx&ei=UyjhUuWXHIGCrgHUu4DQCg&usg=AFQjCNFg6gIANJltqd1V2TWkrifTCcOvJA&sig2=cjh5-1HUuFZhmGb_2gNVyQ&bvm=bv.59568121,d.aWM)

Comment: I want a checklistbox inside a Propertygrid. I have much more properties already being controlled by the propertygrid. Actually, I want a dropdownlist of checkboxes inside the propertygrid. I would use list(of checkboxes) to be controlled by propertygrid. I dont´t do this because of two reasons: I just want to control the checked property and not the font, color, etc... The other reason is that I want values to be showed in the propertygrid, not clicking an ellipsis and opening a new windows, etc...

Comment: @Iomed, please formulate this as an answer to be voted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see [Dynamic Type Description Framework for PropertyGrid](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/189521/Dynamic-Properties-for-PropertyGrid)